# How to copy a picture from canvas to clipboard?

Tags: python, clipboard, tkinter

I have some Tkinter canvas and some picture of lines and text on it. Is there an easy way to copy it to a clipboard?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`.postscript`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/canvas-methods.html) method of the canvas to get an Encapsulated PostScript (EPS) representation of the contents.  Then, use `[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org)'s Python bindings ([PythonMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/download/python/) or [PythonMagickWand](http://www.procoders.net/?p=39)) to convert the EPS to a Windows Enhanced Metafile (EMF).  Finally, copy it to the clipboard (e.g. using [nosklo's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457514/how-to-copy-a-picture-from-canvas-to-clipboard#458236)) with the [CF_ENHMETAFILE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649013(VS.85).aspx) clipboard format.

Answer (score 4):

To use windows clipboard you must convert the image data to a format accepted by win api. Then, just use this function:

```
import win32clipboard

def send_to_clibboard(clip_type, data): 
    win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
    win32clipboard.EmptyClipboard()
    win32clipboard.SetClipboardData(clip_type, data) 
    win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
```

Where `clip_type` can be `win32clipboard.CF_BITMAP`, `win32clipboard.CF_TIFF` or many others.

Comment: I can't make this work.  You can't just pass raw data to `SetClipboardData` - it needs to be a Windows handle, created using `CreateBitmap` or `CreateEnhMetaFile` Win32 functions.  The win32all package does not expose `CreateEnhMetaFile`, so there seems to be no way to put a vector image on the clipboard from Python.  Or am I missing something?