# How to copy image file from system to clipboard

Tags: python, windows, clipboard

I'm new so if the question isn't clear please let me know.

I want to be able to paste an image by pressing  `ctrl + v` but I can't figure out **how to copy the image file** to system `clipboard` to begin with.

I tried to use `PIL` but no luck. I tried `win32clipboard` but for some reason, I can't install the package. python 3.7

Comment: I find tons of answers on Stack Overflow alone. For example https://stackoverflow.com/q/457514/2564301

Comment: @usr2564301 I did too. though this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/488541/10498212 is hard to understand. if you could translate that to noobie language i'll be grateful.

Comment: @Omri what Operating System are you using?

Comment: WINDOWS @ti7 please don't duplicate because that answer is not READABLE.
I have a file on my desktop, which I want to copy to clipboard. its different from canvas

Comment: ... well, "tons" = "lots and lots". I am sure *some* contain noobie friendly code. Pick a method and try.